# please evaluate this sum

Tags: summation, exponential-sum, divisor-sum

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\times\frac{3^{a+n}}{a+n}-\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\times\frac{1}{a+n}$$

I need help evaluating the above, step by step would help.

Thanks

for a>0

or this is the same

http://pokit.org/get/img/2edce16d2f44e070850e02daf2c58e08.png